# Creating a multiview application without storyboards?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm a beginner leearning Xcode, and I created a simple single view application for a pretty useless card game (it's not even really a game).

What I want to know is is it possible to import my single view application into an application with storyboards without having to make a new project and retyping all of the code and connections?

Or is it possible to make a multiview application without storyboards, that I could continue off in the same project?

If so, can anyone direct me to a resource to do so? Thanks.

Comment: This book goes through iphone SDK from code (no designers or etc...).  IMHO, it's a good place to start so you understand it.  Then the designers are a convenience, not a crutch.  http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596523190.do

Answer (score 1):

You can make a multiview application without using `Storyboard`.

Make a new `UIViewController` with a nib

Apple's example of presented a view controller programmatically

```
- (void)add:(id)sender {
   // Create the root view controller for the navigation controller
   // The new view controller configures a Cancel and Done button for the
   // navigation bar.
   RecipeAddViewController *addController = [[RecipeAddViewController alloc]
                       init];

   // Configure the RecipeAddViewController. In this case, it reports any
   // changes to a custom delegate object.
   addController.delegate = self;

   // Create the navigation controller and present it.
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                             initWithRootViewController:addController];
   [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

If you are using an nib though you would want to allocated as followed:

```
RecipeAddViewController *addController = [[RecipeAddViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:@"yourNibName" bundle: nil];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go with @Alex answer.
And you can also add "`Storyboard`" in your project.

Steps to add storyboard are as follows:-
**1. Add new file => Click on "User Interface" tab on left side => Select storyboard => Choose Device type => and create. A blank storyboard file has been created.

2. Now, drag-drop a `UIViewController` from list of objects(right side) and reference it with your view controller class.**
In the same way, you can add other views using storyboard and create multi-view app.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just copy your source and header files of choice to whichever project you like (beware of enabled/disabled [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), though). Also, you can mix storyboards and nib files as you wish. [Here's a little documentation on nibs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW19) that you might find interesting. Basically, you can init a `UIViewController` with it's nib file like this:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```